# stable diffusionをGoogle Colaboratoryを用いて使用したい

Tags: google-colaboratory

[無料のAIイラストstable diffusionをGoogle Colaboratoryを用いて使用する方法 (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyQfQYwvxlY&ab_channel=%E3%82%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A%E6%97%A5%E5%B8%B8%E3%81%AE%E7%96%91%E5%95%8F%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E7%BE%8E%E5%B0%91%E5%A5%B3)

上のyoutubeの講座を見ながらコードをGoogleColabに記載して実行したのですがエラーになります。

動画の概要欄にあるコードを1から順にGoogleColabに書いて実行。
１番目の「# 必要ライブラリをインストール」　の項目でエラーになりました。

エラーメッセージを翻訳しても意味が分からずどうすればよいかご回答いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

下記のコード４行目に赤波線がでます。

```
! pip install diffusers==0.8.0 transformers scipy ftfy pytorch_lightning fire gradio
! git clone https://github.com/lisa-smallbird/Sta... misc
! cp -prf misc/.* ./
from diffusion_client import DiffusionClient
dc = DiffusionClient()
```

下記がコード実行結果です。

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: diffusers==0.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: transformers in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (4.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ftfy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (6.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytorch_lightning in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fire in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gradio in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (3.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: regex!=2019.12.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from diffusers==0.8.0) (2022.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from diffusers==0.8.0) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from diffusers==0.8.0) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from diffusers==0.8.0) (6.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: huggingface-hub>=0.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from diffusers==0.8.0) (0.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from diffusers==0.8.0) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from diffusers==0.8.0) (3.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from transformers) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from transformers) (6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.27 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from transformers) (4.64.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tokenizers!=0.11.3,<0.14,>=0.11.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from transformers) (0.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth>=0.2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from ftfy) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: lightning-utilities>=0.4.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (1.13.1+cu116)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec[http]>2021.06.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (2022.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchmetrics>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from fire) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from fire) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altair>=4.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (1.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-multipart in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (0.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ffmpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (3.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: fastapi in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (0.89.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aiofiles in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (22.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets>=10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (10.4)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown-it-py[linkify,plugins] in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: uvicorn in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (0.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: orjson in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (3.8.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (1.10.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pydub in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (0.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: httpx in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (0.23.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodome in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from gradio) (3.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from altair>=4.2.0->gradio) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from altair>=4.2.0->gradio) (0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from altair>=4.2.0->gradio) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from aiohttp->gradio) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from aiohttp->gradio) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from aiohttp->gradio) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from aiohttp->gradio) (1.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from aiohttp->gradio) (22.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from aiohttp->gradio) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from aiohttp->gradio) (6.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from packaging>=20.0->transformers) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pandas->gradio) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pandas->gradio) (2022.7)
Requirement already satisfied: starlette==0.22.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from fastapi->gradio) (0.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: anyio<5,>=3.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from starlette==0.22.0->fastapi->gradio) (3.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: rfc3986[idna2008]<2,>=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from httpx->gradio) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from httpx->gradio) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: httpcore<0.17.0,>=0.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from httpx->gradio) (0.16.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from httpx->gradio) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata->diffusers==0.8.0) (3.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mdurl~=0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from markdown-it-py[linkify,plugins]->gradio) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mdit-py-plugins in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from markdown-it-py[linkify,plugins]->gradio) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: linkify-it-py~=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from markdown-it-py[linkify,plugins]->gradio) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from matplotlib->gradio) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from matplotlib->gradio) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->diffusers==0.8.0) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->diffusers==0.8.0) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->diffusers==0.8.0) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from uvicorn->gradio) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: h11>=0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from uvicorn->gradio) (0.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0->altair>=4.2.0->gradio) (0.19.3)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources>=1.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0->altair>=4.2.0->gradio) (5.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: uc-micro-py in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from linkify-it-py~=1.0->markdown-it-py[linkify,plugins]->gradio) (1.0.1)
Cloning into 'misc'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
cp: cannot stat 'misc/.*': No such file or directory
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-55497932b2aa> in <module>
      2 get_ipython().system(' git clone https://github.com/lisa-smallbird/Sta... misc')
      3 get_ipython().system(' cp -prf misc/.* ./')
----> 4 from diffusion_client import DiffusionClient
      5 dc = DiffusionClient()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diffusion_client'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

動画の概要欄では URL が省略表示されてしまっており、そのままコピペでは正常に実行できていません。
(= ライブラリのインストールに失敗している)

**参照したページ上の表記:**

```
!git clone https://github.com/lisa-smallbird/Sta... misc
```

**実際に実行すべきコマンド:**

```
!git clone https://github.com/lisa-smallbird/Stable-Diffusers-Misc misc
```

念のため補足すると、2 のソースコード中にも URL が省略表記されている箇所があるので注意してください。